# Amenable groups

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that the countable group $G$ has a left invariant mean on $l^\infty \left(G\right)$ , $L_l$ , and suppose that $G$ has a right invariant mean on $l^\infty \left(G\right)$ , $L_r$.

Please show that $G$ has a mean which is invariant under both left and right translations simultaneously.

I know that exists an isomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow G$ such that for every $g\in G$ if we denote $l_g:G\rightarrow G$ by $l_g(h)=gh$ and we denote $r_g:G\rightarrow G$ by $r_g(h)=hg$ so we get $\phi\circ l_g = r_g \circ \phi$.

I tried to use it somehow unsuccessfully.

Can someone light me up? or maybe I'm in the wrong way at all. any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\mu: l_\infty(G)\to {\mathbb R}$ is a right-invariant mean, 
$\mu f(xg)=\mu f(x)$ for all $g\in G$ and all bounded functions $f(x)$ on $G$. Consider now $\nu: f(x)\mapsto \mu(f(x^{-1}))$. Then $\nu$ is a left-invariant mean.

Edit: The relevant answer is: Proposition 4.4.4 in "Cellular Automata and Groups", 
by Tullio Ceccherini-Silberstein and Michel Coornaert, which shows that left-amenability implies existence of a bi-invariant mean (countability is not needed).

Comment: This does not appear to be what was asked for: that a left-amenable right-amenable group is amenable.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: Oops, you are right, I misread the question.